# Log pid than cpu higher than a value

Tags: logging, cpu-usage, pid

I'm looking for a way to log the pid of process higher than a fixed value of cpu (ex 40%).

I tried with command like this :
`ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1,2 -r | head -10`

But, first, it sorts by the first column of the output, not by the first value ... (1,20,2,3,31,4 ...), and strangly, the `ps` command doesn't show me the process higher than 20%! (I know there is some, by `top`).

Tks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want show the processes of all users, for which you can use:

```
ps -eoax
```

Comment: I just red a post that explain the value of cpu by 'ps' is not what I expected. The post #58539 quote the man pages : "CPU usage is currently expressed as the percentage of time spent running
   during the entire lifetime of a process.". So I don't have the same value with 'ps' as with 'top'.

Answer (score 0):

reading `man sort` I see the `-n` option

> -n, --numeric-sort
>
> compare according to string numerical value

so I assume adding `-n` will sort numerically

```
ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1,2 -r -n | head -10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `top` like this :

```
top -b -n1 | tail -n+8 | awk '$9 > 40 { print $1 }'
```